# Can std::bit_cast be applied to an empty object?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, constexpr, bit-cast

Is it allowed to apply `std::bit_cast` to an object of empty class, converting it to some not-empty class of the same size? And especially is it allowed to do in a constant expression?

I was surprised to find that the following simple program

```cpp
#include <bit>

struct A {};

struct B { unsigned char b; };

// ok in MSVC and GCC, fail in Clang
static_assert( 0 == std::bit_cast<B>(A{}).b );
```

is accepted by both GCC and MSVC, and only Clang complains:

```
error: static assertion expression is not an integral constant expression
```

Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/cGW3Mq3je

What is the correct behavior here according to the standard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [[bit.cast]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4950/bit.cast#2):

> [...] A bit in the value representation of the result is indeterminate if it does not correspond to a bit in the value representation of *from* [...].
> For each bit in the value representation of the result that is indeterminate, the smallest object containing that bit has an indeterminate value; the behavior is undefined unless that object is of unsigned ordinary character type or std​::​byte type. [...]

So, in your case, the behavior of the expression is undefined, but not because of the `std::bit_cast` itself.

Because the bits of `b` do not correspond to any bit of the value representation of `A{}`, they are indeterminate and the value of `b` itself is consequently indeterminate. Only because `b` has type `unsigned char`, this is not immediately undefined behavior.

However, for the comparison with `0 ==`, you then read the value of `b`, which causes undefined behavior because its value is indeterminate.

Of course, because you are using the comparison as the condition in a `static_assert`, the program will not have undefined behavior, but will be ill-formed instead, because the expression is not a constant expression. In a constant expression any lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on an indeterminate value is disallowed. The compiler needs to diagnose this and therefore only Clang is conforming.